# Spring-boot-devtools not restarted when change groovy-files

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

In my project I work with spring-boot and groovy. Also I using spring-boot-devtool. This is a good tool that helps me.

But, when I change groovy-files, server not restarted, I have to change other files

Like a IDE I use a IDEA. The project assembled and tested with the command

```
gradle bootRun
```

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `<CTRL+F9>`

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0-RELEASE with groovy only.

Maybe this auto-generated demo project may help you to compare what went wrong with your project, using [Sring CLI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli-using-the-cli.html) (installed via [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/)):

- run in command line: `spring init --dependencies=devtools,web --type=gradle-project --language=groovy example`
- Import to `IDEA`
- run `gradle bootRun`
- change source and hit `<CTRL+F9>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case pattern `!?*.groovy` was absent in Resource patterns in Compiler settings